# How do I extract multiple div class from google search?

Tags: python, selenium, text, extract

I'd like to extract multiple nationalities to text on my python code using selenium.

for example, musician Zedd's case
https://www.google.com/search?q=musician+Zedd+nationality

He is found to be 'German' and 'Russian'

How do I extract both texts?

(its' div class name is currently : "bVj5Zb FozYP")

```js
Nationality = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "/html/body//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' bVj5Zb FozYP ')]").text
```

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Nationality = [ x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="bVj5Zb FozYP"]')]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly on specific case : Zedd's nationality. However, when I try to find out others in three try-except code, it shows, "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable" any thoughts? :)